# Protractor and virtual machines: test clicks on dropdown menu item before dropdown menu is ready

Tags: drop-down-menu, protractor, windows-server-2012-r2

Here is the situation:

I run my tests on two different platforms: my personal machine (Windows 10) and a virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 r2).

My tests run well on my PC. On my VM however, only one thing fails. Sometimes, when test clicks on the "Logout" link in a dropdown menu, the test thinks it have clicked on it but nothing happened. So the test is indefinitely waiting for the home page...

My question is : Is it possible to force Protractor to

- let the mouse over the dropdown menu,
- wait for some custom time,
- click on the desired item ?

Important notes (don't hesitate to ask clarifications):

- Other dropdown menus do not cause that problem. After discussion with my team, this particular dropdown menu could load its elements faster than the others. So it could be possible that the dropdown menu is loaded before the graphic card renders it, the test then clicks on its item, but the graphic card did not render the item yet. The test would think everything is ok, but nothing happened.
- However, the browser run as a background process:
  Previously my tests randomly crashed on VM and I asked help. I received an answer suggesting to run my tests on headless browsers.
  I did not find a proper way of running headless browsers on Windows Server directly (all suggestions seemed to imply a lot of configuration, like installing a Unix VM). Instead I found a command line tool called Nircmd. Among other things, it allows hiding windows, i.e. I can write a command that makes a process run in background rather than being visible. Now my tests run properly with the exception of that specific dropdown menu.
- If you look at my code, you will see that I explicitly wait for some actions. This is because the application I test is using a timeout that forces me to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`

Here is the code I use:

```
var AtlasLogout = function () {
var localLogoutLink = atlasPage.logOutLink;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(localLogoutLink.getElement()))
.then(function () {
    localLogoutLink.clickOnDropDownMenuItem();
})
.then(function () {
    console.log("Clicked on logout");
})
return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath('//input[@value="Login"]')), PAGE_WAITING_TIME));
```

The **getElement** function returns a ElementFinder using the method (css, xpath or something) defined in an external file where all my page elements are defined.

The **localLogoutLink** is an object of custom type **dropDownMenuItem**. This type has custom methods, like **clickOnDropDownMenuItem**. The definition of **dropDownMenuItem** is here:

```
var dropDownMenuItem = function (dropdownMenu, item) {
var self = this;
self.item = item;
self.dropdownMenu = dropdownMenu;

self.clickOnDropDownMenuItem = function () {
    browser.actions().mouseMove(self.dropdownMenu.getElement()).click(self.item.getElement()).perform();
}
};
```